# Compression algorithm for low performance, low memory device

Tags: algorithm, performance, real-time, accelerometer, compression

I have a question regarding data compression.

- Platform is Cortex M0 50MHz
- Memory is 8K SRAM / 16K Flash (available actual memory for compression algorithm is 2K/4K)
- Data is motion sensor data (2 bytes x,y,x for accelerometer, gyroscope) sampled with 50~100Hz
- Realtime compression for transmission over Bluetooth LE

I have a Cortex M0 board with BLE and I connected it to 9-axis sensors.
But the volume of data is higher (2 bytes * 9 axes * 100 Hz) than BLE throughput (about 1000 bytes).
I have to transfer 9-axis raw data from the M0 device to a mobile phone over BLE...

Is there a suitable compression algorithm?

Comment: I think this will be off topic for stack overflow, you might want to try here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Algorithm recommendations are acceptable here. I'm not sure why it calls for "text" compression. It seems to be binary data. Also, Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) thorughput is 270 kbit/s = 30 kByte/s, perhaps the 1000 B is per packet?

Comment: Have you considered [delta encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton (+1) delta is the way for continuous data ... if you have the data already filtered then the compression can get even better (less bits for delta needed). High delta also marks spikes of noise in signal and could be used for further  processing ... (1st derivation of signal)

Comment: for some types of signals is a good way to use Delta and then RLE afterwards ...

Comment: @MSalters : Now, our BLE is not good throughtput. Unfortunately Actual throughtput is MAX 1KB.

Comment: You should provide(gather?) more information about the requirements: do the samples (need to) occur at the same/a fixed rate? (Do you otherwise have to communicate the time between samples?) Do you need (re)sync? Is low latency important? Which is worse: _dropped samples_ or _reduced accuracy_? (In the end of the day, with an information rate exceeding bandwidth, you're screwed.) - At 50/s, I don't get the problem. If four values change, at most, you can set respective bits in an extra byte, transferring only values for channels with their bit set (and the ninth if fewer than four are).